# JPA: get all rows throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am using JPA for persistence layer. Have a simple table EventCategory

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "CATEGORY" }))
public class EventCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long categoryId;

    @NotNull
    private String category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Event> events;

    // getters and setter

}
```

I am trying to get all rows by

```
public List<EventCategory> getAllCategories() {     
    final String query = "SELECT c from EventCategory c";       
    TypedQuery<EventCategory> query1 = em.createQuery(query, EventCategory.class);
    final List<EventCategory> category = query1.getResultList();
    return category;
}
```

But some how I am getting null pointer exception. By running sql query from command prompt I see required result.

Exception stack

```
02:51:52,726 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/OSU-eTicket-EJB-Servlet].[jsp]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cse769.EJB.Service.EventCategoryService.getAllCategories(EventCategoryService.java:45) [OSU-eTicket-EJB-Session-Entity.jar:]
at com.CSE769.servlet.CategoryCreateServlet.getlist(CategoryCreateServlet.java:38) [classes:]
at org.apache.jsp.events_jsp._jspService(events_jsp.java:137)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
```

get all rows works for other tables. Not sure why it is failing here. Am I doing any silly mistake?

---

Entity manager code

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "examples-769-EJB")
EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Try using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. If this does not work, make sure your Java class matches the database table.

Comment: I tried with IDENTITY. Same error. I did not get what you mean by java class matching database table. In table, I see 2 fields, categoryId and category. I have put java class above. I think it is matching

Comment: Errm, NPE means something is null ... in your code. You later admit "em" is null, and provide no code of where it is set. So set "em" correctly.

Comment: I have added Entity manager code to original post. I am very new to JPA. When you say where it is set, I am not sure if it is done in session bean or in persistence.xml. I am still learning to use JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code that you have put of getAllCategories() is right, then the only posibility is that the entity manager (em) in getAllCategories() is null. You'll see it if you debug or put a message before creating the query.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is null. Do you know how to fix it? I am very new to JPA. It works fine for other tables. Not sure why it is just failing for this

Comment: @CRS I'm not sure if I can help much, the few times I had to configure the EntityManager myself, I didn't use injection. Is the entity manager working in other parts of the application? Are you sure that "examples-769-EJB" is the right name? Are you sure that EventCategoryService is properly declared with all the annotations and (if applicable) the right references in xml files?

Comment: Thank you for the response. examples-769-EJB is correct. I have other methods like createCategory which is working fine.